# HDD is set to readonly mode periodically

Tags: hard-drive, sata, smart

I have a homeserver with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS installed. It is running nextcloud 14.0.1, which executes some cronjob tasks every 15 minutes. I have two own cronjobs, which are executed once a minute.

Since a few weeks my homeserver sets the data HDD to readonly. It started just once or twice a week, but now it occurs every few hours. Most of the time the problem started with a very high CPU load for about 45 minutes, repeating the behaviour after exactly one hour. After doing so for a couple of times the HDD is finally set to readonly.
The CPU load is caused by the nextcloud cronjobs, which should normally not be a problem.

This is the log content:

```
Oct  9 12:51:22 Server kernel: [17693.908851] ata1.00: exception Emask 
0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Oct  9 12:51:22 Server kernel: [17693.908872] ata1.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
Oct  9 12:51:22 Server kernel: [17693.908894] ata1.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 26
Oct  9 12:51:22 Server kernel: [17693.908894]          res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Oct  9 12:51:22 Server kernel: [17693.908910] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Oct  9 12:51:22 Server kernel: [17693.908924] ata1: hard resetting link
Oct  9 12:51:32 Server kernel: [17703.911383] ata1: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
Oct  9 12:51:32 Server kernel: [17703.911402] ata1: hard resetting link
```

Am I right that there is no response (or a delay) from the harddrive?
Is this the reason for the system to set the whole drive to readonly mode?

I tried searching for a solution, but the solutions I found didn't seem to fit my problem.

- the HDD is pretty new and passed the SMART-test
- the filesystem seems to be fine
- the SATA cable is brandnew and I already replaced it with another one

Another solution I found was the update of the firmware of Marvell SATA Controllers. Some versions caused such an issue. But as there is no Marvell Controller in my server I wonder if other Controllers also have a bug like this.

My Controller:
`Intel Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller`

What can I do to get rid of this error? I don't really want to restart the server multiple times a day.